# Sub Query with In Case and Where clause

Tags: sql

```sql
DECLARE @CompanyIds VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CompanyIds=N'64,62'
SELECT 
   cmp.* 
FROM 
   dbo.Company AS cmp  
WHERE 
   cmp.CompanyId IN ( 
      CASE WHEN IsNull(@CompanyIds,'0') = '0' OR @CompanyIds = '' 
      THEN (cmp.CompanyId)
      ELSE (   
               SELECT 
                  Id 
               FROM 
                  dbo.UDF_DP_SplitString(@CompanyIds,',') 
           ) 
      END
   )
```

Query gives me an error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

But I need more values, how can handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `CASE ELSE` condition will yield multiple result during your `WHERE` condition. Convert this to subquery instead.

```
Declare @CompanyIds Varchar(Max)
Set @CompanyIds=N'64,62'
Select cmp.* From dbo.Company as cmp  Where cmp.CompanyId In
     (Select case when IsNull(@CompanyIds,'0')='0' Or @CompanyIds='' then cmp.CompanyId else t1.ID  
        From dbo.UDF_DP_SplitString(@CompanyIds,',') t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic correctly, you should be able to just do away with that `CASE` expression entirely:

```
SELECT cmp.*
FROM dbo.Company cmp
WHERE
    (ISNULL(@CompanyIds, '0') = '0' OR @CompanyIds = '') OR
    cmp.CompanyId IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.UDF_DP_SplitString(@CompanyIds, ','));
```

The predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` or `ELSE`) has to be a literal value, not another logical expression.  As I have written it above, it uses the same logic you intended but without `CASE`.

Comment: but i want to use case  that than sir?